# Accept-Language header does not work as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, http-headers, urllib2

I am using the following code for request a page in english and get tree structure:

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen      
req = Request(url)
req.add_header('Accept-Language', 'en-US')
resp = urlopen(req)      
target = lxml.html.parse(resp)
```

The url is = 'http://www.imdb.com/****/'

The site is only in English, as exception of the titles of movies that change language, I think 
due to browser language.

With the code shown I still have the titles of the movies in Spanish and not in English.

I tried to enter page with a  anonymous browser like tor. And the titles are in English.

Have any idea that I can do to get the page completely in English from Python?

Comment: Can you please show full url ?

Comment: In http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0407362 I see "Galáctica, estrella de combate"

Comment: Which language your browser have ?

Comment: I see the title in spanish obtained from 'target' object in the above code

Comment: When I changed my browsers language to Spanish , the URL still opening in English with English titles.\

Comment: So the only thing I can think is that the language of the titles changed to the region of the IP address. How odd.

Comment: Can you please change value `en` to `en-US` ?

Comment: The result is the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67609/discussion-between-fledgling-and-user3782779).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using at the same time in another thread the imdbpy library. Apparently it was causing some kind of incompatibility.

The code above is correct to request a page in another language.